EPPlus gives A worksheet with this name already exception exists in the workbook
While trying to download a file via EP plus it gives a "A worksheet with this name already exception exists in the workbook"
Any solution we can use apart from checking if worksheet exists?
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(excelSheetName);

I tried searching for better answers related to handling this type of problem but did not find any, is the best solution doing a check and adding the worksheet again?

Search sheet exist: bool isSheetExisted = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Any(x => x.Name == "<Your sheet name>");. If true then perform your logic.

You get the exception at the line that you have posted? Why do you want to add a new excel sheet with a name that already exists? What do you actually want to do?

Majorly speaking this error does not happen every time. It only happens in some instances. Clearing the cache and trying to download again absolves me from such errors. Therefor I think below check will be a help.

WorkSheets contains GetEnumerator() method, so you can work with the LINQ method to check the sheet name exists before inserting.
using System.Linq;

ExcelWorksheet worksheet;
bool isSheetExisted = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Any(x => x.Name == excelSheetName);
if (isSheetExisted)
{
    // Handling when sheet name existed
}
else
{
    worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(excelSheetName);
}

